# What makes two periodic functions identical if one is cos and the other is sin?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I am attempting an assignment in the MIT course "Signals and Systems". There is a question I don't understand. Here it goes:

> **With $x(t) = \cos(\omega _x(t + \tau_x) + \theta_x)$ and $y(t) = \sin(\omega _y(t + \tau_y) + \theta_y)$,**
>   **determine for which of the  following  combinations  x(t)  and  y(t)** 
>   **are  identically  equal  for  all  t.**
>
> a) $ \\\omega _x=\frac\pi3$,  $\tau_x=0, \theta_x=2\pi,\omega _y=\frac\pi3$,  $\tau_y=1, \theta_y=\frac{-\pi}{3} $

The answer:

> If  $\omega _x(t + \tau_x) + \theta_x=\omega _y(t + \tau_y) +
>  \theta_y+2\pi k\\$  for any integer **k**, then $y(t)=x(t)$ for all
>   $t$

Since it is satisfied for this question, the combination is right.

I dont understand how this is equal. If you sub in the values, how is $\cos(\frac\pi3t)=\sin(\frac\pi3t)$? The formula doesn't make sense to me as a result.

Am I missing something?
Here is the actual question: https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw02.pdf

Comment: With the posted values $x(0)=1 \ne 0 = y(0)\,$, so something is wrong with either the quoted answer or the transcription.

Comment: You can check the question yourself(P 2.1 b.) :[link](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw02.pdf)

Comment: I would presume a typo - for example, having both $x$ and $y$ should be the same trig function would make this correct. Everything else looks like it'd take many many more changes.

Comment: @hellowurf You are right and the proposed answer is wrong. From the phrasing of their solution, it sounds like the problem was meant to read $y(t)= \color{red}{\cos}(\dots)$ rather than $=\sin(\dots)$.

Answer (score 0):

basically use the identities ...
$$\sin(x) = cos(\frac\pi2 - x) =cos(x-\frac\pi2) $$
for convenience of notation I will absorb the $\tau$'s and $\theta$'s into phase shift angles $\alpha$ ...

Let $\alpha _x \equiv \omega_x\tau_x+\theta_x$

and  $\alpha _y \equiv \omega_y\tau_y+\theta_y$

So we have 
$$ \cos( \omega_x t +\alpha_x) =\sin( \omega_y t +\alpha_y)$$
using the first identity we get
$$ \cos( \omega_x t +\alpha_x) =\cos(\frac \pi 2-( \omega_y t +\alpha_y))$$

This will be satisfied when the arguments of the trig functions differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$

the equation ...
$$ \omega_x t +\alpha_x =2 k \pi +\frac \pi 2-( \omega_y t +\alpha_y)$$

must be true for all real $t$ and some integer $k$
since true for all $t$ we must have 
$$ \omega_x=-\omega_y \text{ and }\alpha_x+\alpha_y = (2k+\frac 12)\pi$$

using the second identity you get another set of possibilities ...
$$ \omega_x=\omega_y \text{ and }\alpha_x-\alpha_y = (2k-\frac 12)\pi$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question. The OP obviously knows the basics since they were able to spot the mistake in the proposed solution to begin with, which is what the question was all about.